# HtmlAgilityPack substring of all by length

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have html with nested elements (mostly just **div** and **p** elements)
I need to return the same html, but substring'ed by a given number of letters. Obviously the letter count should not enumerate through html tags, but only count letters of InnerText of each html element.
Html result should preserve proper structure - any closing tags in order to stay valid html.

Sample input:

```html
<div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text</p>
    <div>
        <p>some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text</p>
        <p>some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Given `int length = 16` the output should look like this:

```html
<div>
    <p>some text</p> // 9 characters in the InnerText here
    <p>some mo</p> // 7 characters in the InnerText here; 9 + 7 = 16;
</div>
```

Notice that the number of letters (including spaces) is 16. The subsequent `<div>` is eliminated since the letter count has reached variable `length`. Notice that output html is still valid.

I've tried the following, but that does not really work. The output is not as expected: some html elements get repeated.

```cs
public static string SubstringHtml(this string html, int length)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    int totalLength = 0;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
    {
        totalLength += node.InnerText.Length;
        if(totalLength >= length)
        {
            int difference = totalLength - length;
            string lastPiece = node.InnerText.ToString().Substring(0, difference);
            output.Append(lastPiece);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            output.Append(node.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

@SergeBelov provided a solution that works for the first sample input, however further testing presented an issue with an input like the one below.

Sample input #2:

```html
some more text some more text 
<div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text</
</div>
```

Given that variable `int maxLength = 7;` an output should be equal to *some mo*.
It does not work like that because of this code where `ParentNode = null`:

```html
lastNode
    .Node
    .ParentNode
    .ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode(lastNodeText.InnerText.Substring(0, lastNode.NodeLength - lastNode.TotalLength + maxLength)), lastNode.Node);
```

Creating a new HtmlNode does not seem to help because its InnterText property is readonly.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Anything other than expected output? If so how is your input and what do you expect as output?

Comment: I've elaborated with sample input and expected output

Comment: Why does `<p>some mo</p>` include only 14 chars? Why did you skip the second `div`?

Comment: @L.B He kind of explained that in the beginning paragraph of the question. He doesn't include the html tags in the character count, only the InnerText of each node. So, `some text` + `some mo` = 16 characters. As to why the second `<div>` is ignored, I can't say.

Comment: @IchabodClay Please write an answer if you understand the question instead of replying to me. Question isn't clear to me.

Comment: Thanks @IchabodClay for stepping in with explanations and sorry guys for unclear requirements. @IchabodClay is absolutelly right about first part. Now, the second `<div>` is ignored because the letter count has reached `int length` variable, 16 and thus no more text is needed. Remember, this is kind of a `String.Substring()` function, just for html.

Comment: I've updated questions to resemble these details. Hopefully this is clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The small console program below illustrates one possible approach, which is:

1. Select relevant text nodes and calculate the running total of length for them;
2. Take as many nodes as required to get to the running total past the max length;
3. Remove all element nodes from the document except the ones that are ancestors of the nodes we selected during steps ##1, 2;
4. Cut the text in the last node of the list to fit the max length.

**UPDATE:** This should still work with a text node being the first; probably, a `Trim()` is required to remove the whitespace from it as below.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int maxLength = 9;
        string input = @"
            some more text some more text 
            <div>
                <p>some text</p>
                <p>some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text</
            </div>";

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(input);

        // Get text nodes with the appropriate running total
        var acc = 0;
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode
            .Descendants()
            .Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text && n.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0)
            .Select(n => 
            {
                var length = n.InnerText.Trim().Length;
                acc += length;
                return new { Node = n, TotalLength = acc, NodeLength = length }; 
            })
            .TakeWhile(n => (n.TotalLength - n.NodeLength) < maxLength)
            .ToList();

        // Select element nodes we intend to keep
        var nodesToKeep = nodes
            .SelectMany(n => n.Node.AncestorsAndSelf()
                .Where(m => m.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element));

        // Select and remove element nodes we don't need
        var nodesToDrop = doc.DocumentNode
            .Descendants()
            .Where(m => m.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element)
            .Except(nodesToKeep)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var r in nodesToDrop)
            r.Remove();

        // Shorten the last node as required
        var lastNode = nodes.Last();
        var lastNodeText = lastNode.Node;
        var text = lastNodeText.InnerText.Trim().Substring(0,
                lastNode.NodeLength - lastNode.TotalLength + maxLength);
        lastNodeText
            .ParentNode
            .ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode(text), lastNodeText);

        doc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
```

Comment: +1 for working solution. Indeed it works for the sample input I provided above. However, further testing presented an issue when the whole thing starts with just text element instead of a `<div>`. I've updated question with such sample and my thoughts on the issue.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks. I've had a quick look, it appears that the issue was related to whitespace not being trimmed before taking the substring. Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! In case you are Russian, spasibo, Serega!