# How to create a new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument from a List<HtmlNode> from a first "select/filter" run?

Tags: html, nodes, html-agility-pack, document

Using [html agility pack](https://html-agility-pack.net). How can I create a new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument from a List of nodes which I filtered out of the original .html?

```
//filter orig. .html and get all the nodes I want to edit later
LstAllTablesDocNodes = 
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='pricelist']").ToList();

//now pseudoCode: Of what I would like to do (this would give an Error)
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc2 = 
new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument(LstAllTablesDocNodes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the retrieved nodes and extract their html and combine into one single string. Then place that into your new `HtmlDocument`. For some cases, e.g. with `tr` nodes you may need parent wrapping node (`table` in case of `tr`) in order to not through off html parsing within document.

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc = hw.Load("http://books.toscrape.com/");
        var books = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3/a");
        // Console.WriteLine(books.Count);
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(HtmlNode book in books)
            {
                output.Append(book.OuterHtml);
            }
        var doc2 = new HtmlDocument();
        doc2.LoadHtml(output.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(doc2.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3GqcZQ)

References:

1. [HtmlAgilityPack substring of all by length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13793129/6241235)
2. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-stringbuilder